# clearInterval() not working and returns no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run a function, when a checkbox is checked and stop that function, when the checkbox is not checked.

This is how I tried it:

```
$('#auto').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Interval
        var autoInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
            navi('next');
        }, 1500);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(autoInterval);
    }
});
```

The problem is `clearInterval()` does not work and I get no errors.

https://jsfiddle.net/n339tzff/9/

It will work if my code looks like this:

```
// Interval
var autoInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    navi('next');
}, 1500);

// Auto Play
$('#auto').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        autoInterval;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(autoInterval);
    }
});
```

But then I have another problem... I only want to run the function `navi('next')` when I click on the checkbox and not at the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click, it calls the `setInterval` and stores the result of the call in the `autoInterval` and after ending the function removes it. So you store and lost the `value` of your variable every time in the same call.

Declare the `autoInterval` variable outside of the event handler, to make it independent from the event handler's scope. Also you can wrap your function with a **[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)** to not mutate this variable outside

```
(function() { 

   var autoInterval;

   $('#auto').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         autoInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
           navi('next');
         }, 1500);
      } else {
         clearInterval(autoInterval);
      }
   });

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define autoInterval outside of the event handler function, as after the event has run this variable would be 'discarded'/un-accessable.

```
var autoInterval = null;

$('#auto').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        autoInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
            navi('next');
        }, 1500);
    }
    else if(autoInterval !== null) {
        clearInterval(autoInterval);
        autoInterval = null;
    }
});
```